# ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: .net, sql-server, odbc

When I connect to a SQL Server database with odbc connection with docker I am getting this error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "" requested by the login. The login failed.

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll" ,"--environment=Development"]

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install gcc default-jre graphviz libgraphviz-dev graphviz-dev pkg-config
RUN apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y

#install sqlcmd and odbc and others
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  unixodbc-dev \
  unixodbc \
  libpq-dev 


RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update


RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools

RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN chmod +rwx /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/TLSv1.2/TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/SECLEVEL=2/SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

and my docker compose file is like this

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  web:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./wwwroot:/app/wwwroot
  environment:
    - DATABASE_TYPE=MsSql

    - DATABASE_NAME= mydb
    - DATABASE_WAREHOUSE=
    - DATABASE_ROLE=
    - CONNECTION=Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
         Server};server=192.168.0.125\\sql2017,1433;database=mydb;uid=user;pwd=admin
    - CONNECTION_TYPE=odbc
```

Comment: `server=192.168.0.125\\sql2017,1443;` seems like multiple typos because a) named instances don't work in SQL Server for Linux Docker containers (there's no SQL Browser Service listening on udp/1434) and b) SQL Server's listening port is 1433.

Comment: Where's your Dockerfile for the SQL Server container? Are you creating/restoring the `mydb` database somewhere?

Comment: i have used sql image that is also not working

Comment: Are you creating/restoring the `mydb` database somewhere? SQL Server doesn't create a new database during login just because someone asks for one, responsible server administrators create them with appropriate settings, file locations and resource constraints.

Comment: in my local it is working fine. but when i put this in docker iam getting this error

Comment: I think this is a SQL Server's password policy problem, can you check if you SQL Server container is still running after your login attempt?

Comment: sql server is running after login attempt

Comment: issue resolved. the issue was my ip was wrong in the connection string. this is a working code for docker + dotnet + mssql + odbc driver